# Determine whether function is nested within object

Tags: python

I want to write a decorator that can be applied to single functions and to functions that are nested within objects. The difficulty is that I want the decorator to access object variables (via `self.var`) or function variables (via `kwargs`).

My sample code to decorate a single function looks like:

```
def outer_decorator(var_to_print):
    def inner_decorator(function):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            if var_to_print in kwargs.keys():
                string_to_print = kwargs.get(var_to_print, "")
                print(string_to_print)
            return function(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return inner_decorator

@outer_decorator(var_to_print='var')
def print_something(var=''):
    print('print_second')

print_something(var = 'print_first')
#print_first
#print_second
```

For objects I want to do something similar but instead of accessing `kwargs`, I would like to access `self.var`:

```
        def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
            string_to_print = getattr(self, var_to_print)
            print(string_to_print)
            return function(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

Any ideas on how to check dynamically what wrapper should be applied? I tried to check whether it is a callable, but that seems to apply to both.

Comment: How are you using this decorator with objects? What did you try?

Comment: ` I tried to check whether it is a callable, but that seems to apply to both.`
^ can you give an example? I'm trying to do `callable(var_to_print)` and it gives me `False` as I would expect...

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko: The question is rather whether `callable(normal_function)` and `callable(function_of_object)` evaluate to true, which they both do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `isfunction` from the [inspect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) module.

> Return True if the object is a Python function, which includes functions created by a lambda expression.

```
>>> from inspect import isfunction
>>> class A():
...     pass
... 
>>> def f():
...     pass
... 
>>> a = A()
>>> isfunction(a)
False
>>> isfunction(f)
True
```

Actually, what you want to do is to distinguish between functions and methods by using the same decorator for both. A method is still a function. It is considered a method when you access it from the class or from an instance of the class.
There are two options I can think of.

1. Add an argument to the decorator `@outer_decorator(var_to_print='var', f_type='method')`
2. use [`inspect.getfullargspec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) under the assumption that in your class you would use self as parameter name and your functions will not. Example:

   ```
   if 'self' in inspect.getfullargspec(f)[0]:
   ```